# jquery .get download content fully before rendering

Tags: ajax, jquery, load, get

Is there a way to render content *only* after it's fully downloaded using AJAX/get/load with jQuery?

As it stands currently, the loader shows while the 'html' is being downloaded, but once that's done it starts rendering. There's lots of images in the html so they start loading independently after the render.

Is this good design practice? In my opinion once the loader disappears, everything should render 100%, but of course this will increase load time.

Can I achieve this without any 'hacks'?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#clicks').click(function(){

        $('#portfolio').append("<div id='loader'><img src='images/loader.gif'/></div>");

        $.get("moreProjects.html", function(datas){
            $('#portfolio').append(datas);
        }, 'html').complete(function() { 
            $('#loader').hide();
        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always store the data returned in a variable and then append it in the `complete` function:

```
var returnedData;
$('#clicks').click(function(){

    $('#portfolio').append("<div id='loader'><img src='images/loader.gif'/></div>");

    $.get("moreProjects.html", function(datas){
        returnedData = datas;
    }, 'html').complete(function() { 
        $('#portfolio').append(returnedData);
        $('#loader').hide();
    });

    return false;

});
```

Another option would be to use a hidden div container to load the content and then show on complete:

```
$('#clicks').click(function(){

    $('#portfolio').append("<div id='loader'><img src='images/loader.gif'/></div>");
    $('#portfolio').append("<div id='content' style='display:none'></div>");

    $.get("moreProjects.html", function(datas){
        $('#portfolio #content').append(datas);
    }, 'html').complete(function() { 
        $('#portfolio #content').show();
        $('#loader').hide();
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, i just tested the first one by throttling my connection [cant tell on a fast connection]. The first solution acts the same way, the images still load afterwards. complete is called after the HTML is loaded, im assuming. So this will always result in the images loading independently

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, the last post: [Wait untill all images are loaded](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/wait-until-all-images-are-loaded)

In my opinion what you have to do is to save the html in a variable,
then filter out all the img tags and pass it to the `_loadimages` function
in the post i give you setting the complete callback.

Something like this:

```
var $retData = $(datas);
var $imgs = $retData.find('img');
_loadimages($imgs,function(){
   $('#portfolio #content').append($retData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the HTML, place it on your page or preload with JS, if placing it on your page the images can not be hidden if they are to be loaded, but they can be placed of screen.
When the images are loaded, move the HTML to your portfolio element.

The code below is just an example, not tested, and the load function will probably fire on the first image that is loaded, I think ?
If so you will have to count the images, place a load function on each image, and then show the HTML when all images have loaded, or you could try just attaching the load function to the last image in your HTML, but there is no guarantee that the last image in the markup is also the last to load, but it often is.

There could also be a problem with load if images are cached by the browser, if so you need to find another solution, or turn of caching in $.ajax!

```
$('#clicks').on('click', function(){
    $('#portfolio').append("<div id='loader'><img src='images/loader.gif'/></div>");
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'moreProjects.html',
        datatype: 'html',
        done: function(datas) {
            $('<div id="somediv"></div>').append(datas)
                                         .css({position: 'fixed', left: -5000})
                                         .appendTo('body');
        }
     });
     jqxhr.always(function() {
        $('img', '#somediv').on('load', function() {
            $('#loader').remove();
            $('#portfolio').append($('#somediv').contents());
        });
     });
     return false;
});
```